# Regression in R with grouped variables

Tags: r, regression, dplyr

The dependent variable `Value` of the data frame `DF` is predicted using the independent variables `Mean`, `X`, `Y` in the following way:

```
DF <- DF %>% 
    group_by(Country, Sex) %>%
    do({ 
        mod = lm(Value ~ Mean + X + Y, data = .) 
        A <- predict(mod, .)
        data.frame(., A)
    })
```

Data are grouped by `Country` and `Sex`. So, the fitting formula can be expressed as:

```
Value(Country, Sex) = a0(Country, Sex) + a1(Country, Sex) Mean + a2(Country, Sex) X + a3(Country, Sex) Y
```

However, I want to use this formula:

```
Value(Country, Sex) = a0(Country, Sex) + a1(Country, Sex) Mean + a2(Country) X + a3(Country) Y
```

Where `a2` and `a3` are independent of `Sex`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can when grouping by `Country` and `Sex`. You could just group by `Country` and add interactions with `Sex`:

```
DF <- DF %>% 
group_by(Country) %>%
do({ 
    mod = lm(Value ~ Sex + Mean*Sex + X + Y, data = .) 
    A <- predict(mod, .)
    data.frame(., A)
})
```

or estimate your model in one go adding interactions with `Sex` and `Country`:

```
mod <- lm(Value ~ Sex*Country*Mean + Country*X + Country*Y
A <- predict(mod)
```